# Writing a python c extension that modifies argument

Tags: python, c, python-c-extension

I want to write a c extension with a function that modifies its argument. Is that possible?

helloworld.c

```
#include <Python.h>
// adapted from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_further_extensions.htm


/***************\
* Argument Test *
\***************/
// Documentation string
static char arg_test_docs[] =
    "arg_test(integer i, double d, string s): i = i*i; d = i*d;\n";

// C Function
static PyObject * arg_test(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){
    int i;
    double d;
    char *s;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "ids", &i, &d, &s)){
        return NULL;
    }
    i = i * i;
    d = d * d;
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

// Method Mapping Table
static PyMethodDef arg_test_funcs[] = {
    {"func", (PyCFunction)arg_test,  METH_NOARGS , NULL },
    {"func", (PyCFunction)arg_test,  METH_VARARGS, NULL},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

void inithelloworld(void)
{
    Py_InitModule3("helloworld", arg_test_funcs,
                   "Extension module example3!");
}
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
setup(name='helloworld', version='1.0',  \
      ext_modules=[Extension('helloworld', ['helloworld.c'])])
```

Installation:

```
python setup.py install
```

Test:

```
import helloworld
i = 2; d = 4.0; s='asdf'
print("before: %s, %s, %s" % (i,d,s))
helloworld.func(i,d,s)
print("after: %s, %s, %s" % (i,d,s))
```

Test Result:

```
before: 2, 4.0, asdf
after: 2, 4.0, asdf
```

The integer and double values are not changed.
The result should be "after: 4, 16.0, asdf"

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `int`s and `float`s are immutable in Python. So no, they cannot be modified, period.

Comment: I searched online and found that is quite true. is it possible to pass a pointer to the int/flow variable into the function? That way, can the function get and modify the value that the pointer points to? Or this (stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types) can work?

Comment: No. The value cannot be changed. In Python, there is a single `int` object with the value 3. If you do any operation resulting in 3, this object is returned. If somehow you did manage to access the memory location and change its contents to, say, 4, then 1+2 would be 4 everywhere. This would be bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to write a c extension with a function that modifies its argument. Is that possible?

Only to the extent that it's possible with an ordinary function. You can mutate the objects passed to you, if they're mutable, but you can't reassign any variables used to pass you those objects. The C API doesn't let you get around this.

The function you want to write won't work.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. How to write a c extension that mutates the objects passed to the function? Like, taking an int object, and then mutate the object?

Comment: @rxu: Python ints are not mutable.